# Custom mark up language breaks html

Tags: javascript, html

I am using document.write to output HTML to the browser ( I plan to change to .innerHTML soon).

When using view source I can only see the markup, I can not see the HTML output.  However I verified visually that rows 1 and 2 of 0 through 6 are completely missing and commented as such below.

When I inspect the mark up below I see that these two rows have many special characters which leads me to believe this might be the problem.

Note:

Each row is divided by a `||` and each field is divided by a `|`.  The markup lanaguage is properly escaped as you can see there are no superfulous | or ||.

Actually I just noticed the  tag is being cropped for some reason:

```
https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=new+york+city+venture+capitalists&pbx=1&oq=new+york+city+venture+capitalists&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=12&gs_upl=0l0l0l98460l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=94def8e69f73d3d7&biw=1214&bih=852
```

becomes

```
<a class=\'bookmark_tweet\' target=\'_blank\' href=\'https://www.google.com/#hl=en&amp;sclient=psy-ab&amp;q=new+york+city+venture+cap
```

I'll post relevant code once I get it:

Comment: If the problem is content missing from your HTML page, then the problem lies in whatever generates the HTML.  You'll have to ask about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View source shows you what was received from the server.  If you add to it using `document.write()` you won't see that unless you use a DOM inspector in your browser, such as firebug (Firefox).  I know there is one for IE but never use IE so I don't know what it's called.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript strings don't span lines.  You can't open a quote on one line, then close it on another.

Comment: You can span string literals over multiple lines in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Escaping_characters) and [JScript](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=resources%3Aresources&cache=cache&media=resources:jscriptdeviationsfromes3.pdf).